# IIS: autologon from current domain user work on name but on IP

Tags: iis, autologin

Then I try to access my intranet website hosted on IIS server via name : 
http://mywebsite 
I am automatically logged on with my current user (Domain). That's what I want!

If I try to access the website through IP :
http://123.12.1.100 
I receive a login request.

If I save the login in my browser, the login is asked everytime and autofilled by the browser.

After that, I have tried to add an entry in the Windows Identification Information using "mywebsite" not the IP. After that, there is no popup anymore.

Why? How can I make it work through IP the same way as through name?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: The rules always apply, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/browsers/prompt-for-username-and-password

Comment: Something in this article is wrong or I do not understand it correctly.
First, I don't use Internet Explorer, and it still works with name. Also, the last bit about anonymous authentication make no sense to me :
"Internet Explorer prompts for a password when you're using anonymous authentication.

Anonymous authentication never prompts you for a password, because..."

Comment: 1. All browsers follow IE's conventions unfortunately, so even that article is pretty old, no better alternative out there. 2. Focus on the whole article and locate what's the proper section applies to your case. That is "If the computer name portion of the requested URL contains periods ..."

Comment: Ok, but this do not explain the current state of my infrastructure. Why does it work when the authentication is registered in Windows?

Comment: I have no intention to comment more, as I just want to give out some hints on which direction you should go. To know more about Windows authentication and how to configure everything up, you should consult your domain administrators. And if they happen to know less than enough, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com to learn from Microsoft directly. Note that such questions are off topic here, as they are not programming related.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I didn't expect this to be off topics here but now, I know.